# Reversing n characters of a file

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to write a small program to reverse the first n characters of the text in a file. I wrote this::

```
void getdata(FILE *fp)
{
    char ch;
    printf("Enter text::\n");
    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
        fputc(ch,fp);
}

void printdata(FILE *fp)
{
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
        putchar(ch);
}

void reverse(FILE *fp, int n)
{
    char ch[20];
    for( int i=0;i<n;++i)
        ch[i]=fgetc(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("%.*s\n",n,ch); //printing the string
    while(n--)
        fputc(ch[n-1],fp);
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int n;
    fp=fopen("music.txt","w+");
    getdata(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("Number of chars to reverse:: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    reverse(fp,n);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("After reversing text is::\n");
    printdata(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is 
[image]

Where am i going wrong? Why is there a 'u' ?
**EDIT**: I could get it work by replacing the while loop with

```
for( int i=0;i<n;++i)
        fputc(ch[n-1-i],fp);
```

But what is the fault in the while?

Comment: @Javia1492 heh? rather you should advice, as `EOF` might not fit in a `char`, change the `ch` type to `int`.

Comment: @Lokesh Jaddu And, if you didn't notice, potential buffer overflow in function `reverse()`.

Comment: @Javia1492 1) which line did you find `eof()`? Please point that out for me. 2) what is the return type of `getchar()`? and i'm not _implying_ anything. I'm _humbly_ telling you, it's bad. Hope you don't mind. :-)

Comment: @Javia1492 good, happy I could help. Let's remove the unnecessary comments then, shall we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault in your while is that first loop decrement `n`. In your use case `n` start from `4` instead of `5`. Then the you assign the char at `n-1`, that means that the `n` has to start from `5`. At the end your loop is `4` time long instead of `5`.

Change

```
while(n--)
        fputc(ch[n-1],fp);
```

to

```
do
{
   fputc(ch[n-1],fp);
}while(--n);
```

Another little thing. Your reverse function is not checking that n passed cannot be > of ch length, in your case 20.

Comment: Good catch. The `while (n--) ...` construct is still a good idiom for iterating backwards, but it has to access `ch[n]` instead of `ch[n-1]`. A straightforward solution without obscure indexing would therefore be `while (n--) fputc(ch[n], fp);`.

Comment: Yes, sure. Your solution faster. My solution was to be, I hope, more clear for OP.

Comment: Your answer is good. It was more of an additional comment. (Maybe just to myself, because I had looked at the code and failed to see the error. That's the problem with idoims: They might lead you to overlook the obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int i=0;i<n;++i)   //consider n as 5
    fputc(ch[n-1-i],fp);//  ch[5-1-0] ch[5-1-1] ch[5-1-2] ...
```

is not equivalent to

```
while(n--)              //consider n as 5
    fputc(ch[n-1],fp);  //ch[4-1] ch[3-1] ....
```

in while loop after `while(n--)` when control reaches `fputc(ch[n-1],fp)` n has already decremented.